# validar numeros negativos

Tags: java

Necesito que un `JTextField` solo pueda aceptar valores de números tanto negativos como positivos pero no logro que me aparezca el '-'. Ya he intentado varias cosas.

```
private void JTPtxKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    char a = evt.getKeyChar();

    if ((a<'0' || a>'9' || /*FALTA LA INSTRUCCION PARA ACEPTAR EL MENOS*/)) evt.consume();
}
```

Comment: Si se detecta el caracter '-' tomar en cuenta que la función podría aceptar cadenas como la siguiente: '8-7---2'. Un enfoque distinto podría ser realizar una validación hasta que se necesite procesar la información del campo (intentando convertir a int su contenido, por ejemplo).

Comment: tienes razón muchas gracias por tu acotación

Answer (score 1):

Yo recomiendo partir la validación del caracter en dos partes.

Parte 1: si el caracter es `'-'` y si el contenido del `JTextField` es vacío, entonces es válido.

Parte 2: si el caracter es dígito, es válido.

En código, esto sería algo como (nota, este código puede reducirse ampliamente):

```
char a = evt.getKeyChar();
boolean valido = false;
if (a == '-') {
    Object component = evt.getComponent();
    if (component instanceof JTextField) {
        JTextField tf = (JTextField)component;
        valido = tf.getText().isEmpty();
    }
} else if (a >= '0' && a <= '9') {
    valido = true;
}
if (!valido) {
    evt.consume();
}
```

Comment: mcuhas gracias por la infomracion me sirvio la acotacion que me sugeristes, ahora me puede explicar como trabaja la siguiente parte del codigo?

Comment: muchas gracias por la información me sirvió la acotación que me sugeriste, ahora me puede explicar como trabaja la siguiente parte del código?                                                                                                                         Object component = evt.getComponent();
    if (component instanceof JTextField) {
        JTextField tf = (JTextField)component;
        valido = tf.getText().isEmpty();
    }

Comment: Es para obtener el componente donde se ejecuta el evento. En este caso, valido que sea un `JTextField` y que el contenido de ese `JTextField` sea jna cadena vacía.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías trabajar con `jspiner` y ya no seria necesario crear nada [Ver aqui](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/publicJSpinnerNumberEditorJSpinnerspinner.htm)